# How client and server mapping message on Spring boot websocket

Tags: spring-boot, stomp, spring-websocket, sockjs

I cloned a chat application project that uses spring boot websocket on github.
Here is code:

```java
@MessageMapping("/chat.private.{username}")
public void filterPrivateMessage(@Payload ChatMessage message, @DestinationVariable("username") String username, Principal principal) {

    message.setUsername(principal.getName());
    simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/user/" + username + "/exchange/amq.direct/chat.message", message);
}
```

Example: **username** variable is: **foo@gmail.com**, it mean the link to for client subscribe should be: **/user/foo@gmail.com/exchange/amq.direct/chat.message**

But in client code:

```js
chatSocket = Stomp.over(new SockJS(url)); //use sockjs and stompjs
chatSocket.subscribe("/user/exchange/amq.direct/chat.message"
```

I do not understand how to the application can send to correct client, when the client listen the different url (without foo@gmail.com).
Can someone explain to me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is the `/user/` prefix in the subscribe url, which will be transformed by Spring to deliver the message to the specific user. It is described in the [User Destinations](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-user-destination) section in the docs:

> An application can send messages targeting a specific user, and Spring’s STOMP support recognizes destinations prefixed with `/user/` for this purpose. For example, a client might subscribe to the destination `/user/queue/position-updates`. This destination will be handled by the `UserDestinationMessageHandler` and transformed into a destination unique to the user session, e.g. `/queue/position-updates-user123`. This provides the convenience of subscribing to a generically named destination while at the same time ensuring no collisions with other users subscribing to the same destination so that each user can receive unique stock position updates.